# MultiIndex DataFrame: Delete non-consecutive indices and re-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex DataFrame, that looks like this:

```
                    Column_1  Column_2  Column_3 
FirstIdx SecondIdx
       0        0          0         0         0
                1          1         1         1
                2          2         2         2
                3          3         3         3
       1        0          4         4         4
                1          5         5         5
                3          6         6         6
                5          7         7         7
                6          8         8         8
```

Now I want to drop all rows that have no direct preceding index and no direct subsequent index, e.g. row with index (1,3). The resulting DataFrame would look like this:

```
                    Column_1  Column_2  Column_3 
FirstIdx SecondIdx
       0        0          0         0         0
                1          1         1         1
                2          2         2         2
                3          3         3         3
       1        0          4         4         4
                1          5         5         5
                5          7         7         7
                6          8         8         8
```

Afterwards I want to reindex the DataFrame so that each SecondIdx with no predecessor increments the FirstIdx and the SecondIdx starts to count from 0:

```
                    Column_1  Column_2  Column_3 
FirstIdx SecondIdx
       0        0          0         0         0
                1          1         1         1
                2          2         2         2
                3          3         3         3
       1        0          4         4         4
                1          5         5         5
       2        0          7         7         7
                1          8         8         8
```

Does pandas implement any convenient and fast way to do these 2 operations (maybe combined in one step)?

Thanks!

Comment: "*maybe combined in one step*" You didn't show any attempt at solving it and you're looking for "best, fastest, shortest" ways all of a sudden? That's kind of rude

Comment: I am sorry if that seemed rude. In my experience, however, there is almost always a way of doing things in pandas, that is "quick and short". I could only manage to do this with multiple for-loops, that's why I asked if there is a faster and more simple way of doing it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create columns by `MultiIndex` and then processing - get consecutive values by differencies per groups, create new groups `g` and for levels of `MultiIndex` use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) and [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()

g = df.groupby('FirstIdx')['SecondIdx'].diff().gt(1).cumsum()
df = df[df.groupby(['FirstIdx', g])['SecondIdx'].transform('size').gt(1)]

df['FirstIdx'] = df.groupby(['FirstIdx', g]).ngroup()
df['SecondIdx'] = df.groupby(['FirstIdx', g]).cumcount()

df = df.set_index(['FirstIdx','SecondIdx'])
print (df)
                    Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
FirstIdx SecondIdx                              
0        0                 0         0         0
         1                 1         1         1
         2                 2         2         2
         3                 3         3         3
1        0                 4         4         4
         1                 5         5         5
2        0                 7         7         7
         1                 8         8         8
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, using a frame version of the index:

```
# get index as frame for convenience
idx = df.index.to_frame()

# set groups of consecutive values
groups = idx.groupby(level='FirstIdx')['SecondIdx'].diff().gt(1).cumsum()

# determines rows to drop (i.e. groups with single values)
mask = idx.groupby([idx['FirstIdx'], groups])['FirstIdx'].transform('size').gt(1)

# compute increment of MultiIndex
increment = (~mask).groupby(level='FirstIdx').cumsum()

# update MultiIndex
idx['FirstIdx'] += increment
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx)

# and drop unwanted rows
df = df.loc[mask.values]
```

output:

```
                    Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
FirstIdx SecondIdx                              
0        0                 0         0         0
         1                 1         1         1
         2                 2         2         2
         3                 3         3         3
1        0                 4         4         4
         1                 5         5         5
2        5                 7         7         7
         6                 8         8         8
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am going to answer of @jezrael as correct, as the "SecondIdx" does not start over from 0 with beginning of "FirstIdx" 2 in your example. Anyway, thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Philipp Oops, I hadn't seen this one ;) Easy to fix with a `groupby`+`cumcount`